# Combining hdf5 files

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I have a number of hdf5 files, each of which have a single dataset. The datasets are too large to hold in RAM. I would like to combine these files into a single file containing all datasets separately (i.e. **not** to concatenate the datasets into a single dataset).

One way to do this is to create a hdf5 file and then copy the datasets one by one. This will be slow and complicated because it will need to be buffered copy.

Is there a more simple way to do this? Seems like there should be, since it is essentially just creating a container file.

I am using python/h5py.

Comment: Looks like this was answered already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346589/concatenate-a-large-number-of-hdf5-files

Comment: @MattPavelle as far as I understand this is different from what I want. I do not want to concatenate the datasets into a single dataset, but to keep them as separate datasets within one file.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the clarification and the edit. And forgive the follow up - it's been a few years since I played with HDF5 - but I assume h5merge doesn't do the trick?

Comment: @MattPavelle Not sure, looking at it now. h5merge does not seem to be part of the official hdf5 tools, and the documentation for it seems kind of poor. I was looking more for a python/h5py solution, but I will also further explore the available hdf5 unix tools. Thanks.

Comment: yeah, it is not an official hdf5 tool - and it's definitely not Pythonic :) but it might be your best bet.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One solution is to use the `h5py` interface to the low-level `H5Ocopy` [function](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5O.html#Object-Copy) of the HDF5 API, in particular the `h5py.h5o.copy` [function](http://api.h5py.org/h5o.html):

```
In [1]: import h5py as h5

In [2]: hf1 = h5.File("f1.h5")

In [3]: hf2 = h5.File("f2.h5")

In [4]: hf1.create_dataset("val", data=35)
Out[4]: <HDF5 dataset "val": shape (), type "<i8">

In [5]: hf1.create_group("g1")
Out[5]: <HDF5 group "/g1" (0 members)>

In [6]: hf1.get("g1").create_dataset("val2", data="Thing")
Out[6]: <HDF5 dataset "val2": shape (), type "|O8">

In [7]: hf1.flush()

In [8]: h5.h5o.copy(hf1.id, "g1", hf2.id, "newg1")

In [9]: h5.h5o.copy(hf1.id, "val", hf2.id, "newval")

In [10]: hf2.values()
Out[10]: [<HDF5 group "/newg1" (1 members)>, <HDF5 dataset "newval": shape (), type "<i8">]

In [11]: hf2.get("newval").value
Out[11]: 35

In [12]: hf2.get("newg1").values()
Out[12]: [<HDF5 dataset "val2": shape (), type "|O8">]

In [13]: hf2.get("newg1").get("val2").value
Out[13]: 'Thing'
```

*The above was generated with `h5py` version `2.0.1-2+b1` and iPython version `0.13.1-2+deb7u1` atop Python version `2.7.3-4+deb7u1` from a more-or-less vanilla install of Debian Wheezy. The files `f1.h5` and `f2.h5` did not exist prior to executing the above.* ***Note that, per [salotz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3524689/salotz), for Python 3 the dataset/group names need to be*** `bytes` ***(e.g.,*** `b"val"`***), not*** `str`.

The `hf1.flush()` in command `[7]` is crucial, as the low-level interface apparently will always draw from the version of the `.h5` file stored on disk, not that cached in memory.  Copying datasets to/from groups not at the root of a `File` can be achieved by supplying the ID of that group using, e.g., `hf1.get("g1").id`.

Note that `h5py.h5o.copy` will fail with an exception (no clobber) if an object of the indicated name already exists in the destination location.

Comment: This looks to be potentially a couple of years too late, but... <shrug>  I'll definitely be using it, and hopefully if nothing else it'll help someone else, too.

Comment: Thanks! Actually this question gets votes every now and then, so I am guessing it is still useful for many people.

Comment: Cool. HDF5 is a really nice data format, but its high-level API is far from... exhaustive.

Comment: I'm using `h5py` 2.7.1 and python 3.6.5 and the strings needed to be bytes, so replace: `h5.h5o.copy(hf1.id, "g1", hf2.id, "newg1")` with `h5.h5o.copy(hf1.id, b"g1", hf2.id, b"newg1")`

Answer (score 36):

This is actually one of the use-cases of HDF5.
If you just want to be able to access all the datasets from a single file, and don't care how they're actually stored on disk, you can use [external links](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/group.html#external-links). From the [HDF5 website](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/):

> External links allow a group to include objects in another HDF5 file and enable the library to access those objects as if they are in the current file. In this manner, a group may appear to directly contain datasets, named datatypes, and even groups that are actually in a different file. This feature is implemented via a suite of functions that create and manage the links, define and retrieve paths to external objects, and interpret link names:

[Here's how to do it in h5py](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/group.html#external-links):

```
myfile = h5py.File('foo.hdf5','a')
myfile['ext link'] = h5py.ExternalLink("otherfile.hdf5", "/path/to/resource")
```

**Be careful:** when opening `myfile`, you should open it with `'a'` if it is an existing file. If you open it with `'w'`, it will erase its contents.

This would be very much faster than copying all the datasets into a new file. I don't know how fast access to `otherfile.hdf5` would be, but operating on all the datasets would be transparent - that is, h5py would see all the datasets as residing in `foo.hdf5`.

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice trick. In my case, though, I prefer them to really be contained in one file. But I might use this method if copying proves to be be too slow.

Comment: this should be selected as the answer to the question.

Comment: If you are going to do this and you have a lot of links, be sure to use H5Pset_libver_bounds() in C or libver='latest' when creating/opening new files in h5py. This will use the latest file format, which is much more efficient for storing large numbers of links.

Comment: I just tried your advice and it made "myfile" that was 98.5GB dataset 960 bytes; which I now have to recreate. No warnings or nothing - poof - 98.5GB gone!

Comment: @JeshuaLacock that happens when you open it with `'w'`. I think the answer should be `myfile = h5py.File('foo.hdf5', 'a')`.

Comment: What happens when you try to scp a h5 file which links to other h5 files?

Answer (score 14):

I found a non-python solution by using [h5copy](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/Tools.html#Tools-Copy) from the official hdf5 tools. h5copy can copy individual specified datasets from an hdf5 file into another existing hdf5 file.

If someone finds a python/h5py-based solution I would be glad to hear about it.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use [ipython](https://ipython.org/) and [h5copy](http:///https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/Tools.html#Tools-Copy) tool togheter, this is much faster compared to a pure python solution. Once installed h5copy.

## Console solution M.W.E.

```
#PLESE NOTE THIS IS IPYTHON CONSOLE CODE NOT PURE PYTHON

import h5py
#for every dataset Dn.h5 you want to merge to Output.h5 
f = h5py.File('D1.h5','r+') #file to be merged 
h5_keys = f.keys() #get the keys (You can remove the keys you don't use)
f.close() #close the file
for i in h5_keys:
        !h5copy -i 'D1.h5' -o 'Output.h5' -s {i} -d {i}
```

## Automated console solution

To completely automatize the process supposing you are working in the folder were the files to be merged are stored:

```
import os 
d_names = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
d_struct = {} #Here we will store the database structure
for i in d_names:
   f = h5py.File(i,'r+')
   d_struct[i] = f.keys()
   f.close()

# A) empty all the groups in the new .h5 file 
for i in d_names:
    for j  in d_struct[i]:
        !h5copy -i '{i}' -o 'output.h5' -s {j} -d {j}
```

## Create a new group for every .h5 file added

If you want to keep the previous dataset separate inside the output.h5, you have to create the group first using the flag  `-p`:

```
 # B) Create a new group in the output.h5 file for every input.h5 file
 for i in d_names:
        dataset = d_struct[i][0]
        newgroup = '%s/%s' %(i[:-3],dataset)
        !h5copy -i '{i}' -o 'output.h5' -s {dataset} -d {newgroup} -p
        for j  in d_struct[i][1:]:
            newgroup = '%s/%s' %(i[:-3],j) 
            !h5copy -i '{i}' -o 'output.h5' -s {j} -d {newgroup}
```

Answer (score 2):

To update on this, with HDF5 version 1.10 comes a new feature that might be useful in this context called "Virtual Datasets".
Here you find a brief tutorial and some explanations:
[Virtual Datasets](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/Tutor/vds.html).
Here more complete and detailed explanations and documentation for the feature:
[Virtual Datasets extra doc](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/docNewFeatures/NewFeaturesVirtualDatasetDocs.html).
And here the merged pull request in h5py to include the virtual datatsets API into h5py:
[h5py Virtual Datasets PR](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/pull/663) but I don't know if it's already available in the current h5py version or will come later.

Comment: Creating a virtual dataset would (virtually) concatenate the datasets, though, which is not what the original poster wanted to do.

Answer (score 2):

To use Python (and not IPython) and h5copy to merge HDF5 files, we can build on [GM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40234391/4464653):

```
import h5py
import os

d_names = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
d_struct = {} #Here we will store the database structure
for i in d_names:
   f = h5py.File(i,'r+')
   d_struct[i] = f.keys()
   f.close()

for i in d_names:
   for j  in d_struct[i]:
      os.system('h5copy -i %s -o output.h5 -s %s -d %s' % (i, j, j))
```