# How do you concatenate all the HDF5 files in a given directory?

Tags: python, hdf

I have many HDF5 files in a directory and I want to concatenate all of them. I tried the following:

```
from glob import iglob
import shutil
import os

PATH = r'C:\Dropbox\data_files'

destination = open('data.h5','wb')
for filename in iglob(os.path.join(PATH, '*.h5')):
    shutil.copyfileobj(open(filename, 'rb'), destination)
destination.close()
```

However, this only creates an empty file. Each HDF5 file contains two datasets, but I only care about taking the second one (which is named the same thing in each) and adding it to a new file.

Is there a better way of concatenating HDF files? Is there a way to fix my method?

Comment: Its not so straightforward. Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346589/concatenate-a-large-number-of-hdf5-files and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492273/combining-hdf5-files

Comment: I've looked at that post but am not sure how exactly that method works.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? If you did, could you post a self-answer?

Comment: If not, does [this](https://gist.github.com/zonca/8e0dda9d246297616de9) (from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5346589/377366)) solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine [ipython](https://ipython.org/) with [h5py module](http://www.h5py.org/) and [h5copy](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/Tools.html#Tools-Copy) tool.

Once installed h5copy ahd h5py just open the ipython console in the folder where all your .h5 files are stored and use this code to merge them in a `output.h5` file:

```
import h5py
import os 
d_names = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
d_struct = {} #Here we will store the database structure
for i in d_names:
   f = h5py.File(i,'r+')
   d_struct[i] = f.keys()
   f.close()

for i in d_names:
    for j  in d_struct[i]:
          !h5copy -i '{i}' -o 'output.h5' -s {j} -d {j}
```