# Concatenate two big pandas.HDFStore HDF5 files

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, pytables

This question is somehow related to ["Concatenate a large number of HDF5 files"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346589/concatenate-a-large-number-of-hdf5-files).

I have several huge HDF5 files (~20GB compressed), which could not fit the RAM. Each of them stores several `pandas.DataFrame`s of identical format and with indexes that do not overlap.

I'd like to concatenate them to have a single HDF5 file with all DataFrames properly concatenated. One way to do this is to read each of them chunk-by-chunk and then save to a single file, but indeed it would take quite a lot of time.

Are there any special tools or methods to do this without iterating through files?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

see docs [here](http://odo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/hdf5.html) for the `odo` project (formerly `into`). Note if you use the `into` library, then the argument order has been switched (that was the motivation for changing the name, to avoid confusion!)

You can basically do:

```
from odo import odo
odo('hdfstore://path_store_1::table_name',
    'hdfstore://path_store_new_name::table_name')
```

doing multiple operations like this will append to the rhs store.

This will automatically do the chunk operations for you.

Comment: Awesome; first real-world mention of Blaze I've seen in the wild.

Comment: So Blaze is awesome. However this works strangely for me. After running odo as above, eventually I get a giant stack of stdout 'closing file', I think all mentioning the target store, not the source. Does that sound like a bug or am I missing some pre/post steps?